# NULL sequence for CSV-based EXTERNAL TABLE

Tags: csv, hive, amazon-athena

I want to create an `EXTERNAL TABLE` on AWS Athena based on a CSV file that looks as follows:

```
dqcj2u5,51059461201
dqcrtb8,24005401101
dqcjrch,
dqcnk8d,24031701001
dqcwdk2,24003731311
dqcjubw,24031705903
```

That is, in some rows the second column is empty. Is there any way to make these values `NULL` instead of `''` (empty string)?

Comment: Try using `NULL DEFINED AS ''` while creating your table. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-CreateTableCreate/Drop/TruncateTable check for `row_format` definition.

Comment: This is my query thus far: `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE a_b (
 a STRING,
 b STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   'separatorChar' = ','
   )
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION 's3://...';`. I'm not sure where the `NULL DEFINED AS ''` should go.

Comment: `NULL DEFINED AS` doesn't work in combination with `SERDE`s? No problem. Wanna submit that as an answer?